# encrypted password with sonataadminbundle and fosuserbundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In sf2.3 i am using fosuserbundle for usermanagement and sonataadminbundle for admin management.

When i try to create a new user in the admin i create the form field

```
->add('plainPassword');
```

But whenever i persist to the database the userbundle doesnt generate the encrypted password out of the plain password, which means it must be possible to use the usermanagement within the sonataadminbundle.

How to correct set password and persist the encrypted password to the database?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you want to integrate FOSUserBundle yourself and not use SonataUserBundle which does all hard work for you? Password saving is already set up correctly there.

Comment: SonataUserBundle is not in sync with the current Head of sf 2.3 ...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not using the fos user manager to persist your object?

```
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$userManager->update($user,true);
```

The update method takes care of encrypting the passwords as well as several other items such as canocalizating   the user name and email.  The doc files have more information.

Comment: well how can i customize the persisting process in sonataadminbundle? My user Entity is extending fos user model class.

Comment: That's kind of a broad question and I'm not overly familiar with the admin bundles.  There is a Sonata user bundle which might help.  Are you using the doctrine orm?  Do you have use_listener: true in your fos_user config?  The FOS/UserBundle/Doctrine/Orm/UserListener should be intercepting all persist events and updating the password.

Comment: well it seems like it worked all the time. use_listener is set to true by default. It seems like the problem is that when try to update the password using plainPassword doctrine doesnt recognize that there are any changes. When i also update an additional field like enabled or email doctrine flushes the changes and also changes the password to correct encrypted password.

strange...